# How to Flatten JSON in VBA/Excel

Tags: json, vba

I am trying to write a script in Excel that will take a string of JSON and return it flattened. Similar to this that is done in JS.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/zachc/S2hsS/101/embedded/result/

What would be the easiest way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing visible in your linked fiddle.  VBA has no built-in capabilities for working with JSON, so you could start by looking at https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON.  "Easiest" is difficult to answer without any idea of your abilities though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I accidentally pasted the link twice, it should work fine now.

Is there a way to run javascript from VBA or to access the above link and pull down the result?

Comment: You may use any JSON parser for VBA. `flatten` function from JS fiddle by the link could be either converted to VBA, or launched as JS within `htmlfile`. Not sure about pulling down result from the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flatten` function from JS fiddle by the link could be converted to VBA as shown in the below code. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Debug.Print FlattenJSON("{foo:{bar:false,data:[1,[2,[3,4],5],6]}}")

End Sub

Function FlattenJSON(sJSON As String) As String

    Dim sState As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim vResult As Variant

    JSON.Parse sJSON, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then MsgBox "Invalid JSON": End
    JSON.Flatten vJSON, vResult
    FlattenJSON = JSON.Serialize(vResult)

End Function
```

The output for me is as follows:

```js
{
    "foo.bar": false,
    "foo.data[0]": 1,
    "foo.data[1][0]": 2,
    "foo.data[1][1][0]": 3,
    "foo.data[1][1][1]": 4,
    "foo.data[1][2]": 5,
    "foo.data[2]": 6
}
```